# Mongodb Docker init configuration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I have problems with my docker-mongodb configuration. When I try to access my mongodb's collection through mongoose, mongo returns the following error:

```
(base) c27gc@c27gc-desktop:~/Documentos/Code/Development/bloomtasks$ node usecases/get.js 
Testing Connection...
Connection Error: MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/home/c27gc/Documentos/Code/Development/bloomtasks/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at processIncomingData (/home/c27gc/Documentos/Code/Development/bloomtasks/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/c27gc/Documentos/Code/Development/bloomtasks/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at Socket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:719:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 18,
  codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed'
}
```

The file get.js

```
'use strict';


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Repository = require('../Interfaces/repository.js')
const Task = require('../models/task.js');
const User = require('../models/user.js');
const date = require('date-and-time');

const path = 'mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/dbname'

const repository = new Repository(path)
const now = new Date();

repository.create(Task, {
    name: "My Name",
    description: "Test String",
    project: "My Project's Name",
    difficulty: 2,
    startDate: date.format(now, 'ddd, MMM DD YYYY'),
    maxDevelopmentTime: 10,
    expirationDate: date.format(now, 'ddd, MMM DD YYYY'),
    comments: "String",
    deliveryDate: date.format(now, 'ddd, MMM DD YYYY'),
    assigned: false,
    priority: 1,
    reward: 15,
    technologies: ["React", "Nodejs"]
})
```

Class Repository definition:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');


class Repository {
    constructor(path){
        mongoose.connect(path, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
        console.log("Testing Connection...")
        const connection = mongoose.connection;
        connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Connection Error:'));
    }

    create(model, payload) {
        model.create(payload)
        mongoose.connection.close()
    }
}

module.exports = Repository
```

When I change the following line of get.js

```
const path = 'mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/dbname'
```

for

```
const path = 'mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/'
```

This creates a db named "test" and inside of it the collection "tasks". I believe that this error is probably caused by my docker-mongodb setting.
docker-mongodb setting:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  database:
    image: 'mongo'
    container_name: 'mongo-test'
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=dbname
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=username
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro
      - ./mongodata:/data/db
    ports:
      - '27017-27019:27017-27019'
```

init-mongo.js
first try:

```
databases = ['dbname']

for (var i = databases.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  db = db.getSiblingDB(databases[i])

  db.createUser({
    user: "username",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: ["readWrite"]
  })
}
```

second try:

```
db.createUser({
    user: "username",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [
    {
        "role" : "readWrite",
        "db" : "dbname"
    }]
  })
```

Maybe, the init-mongo.js file has not been reconized.
Thanks for your help.